# Export tree view in XLS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs

I have a tree with structure:

```
{
 nodename: {id:'nodename' childIds:['2node']},
 2node: {id:'2node', childIds: []}
}
```

Any ideas or instrument to convert in to XLS file?
Or algorithm, tying about 3 days...

ps. I'm asking for instrument what i can use to transfer json file to xls on pure javascript or ready node module

Comment: You need to make it clear what the desired transformation is, otherwise we have no chance of helping you. [Edit] your question to show us what the output would look like and the progress you have made in the last 3 days.

Comment: Can you explain, what have you tried?

Comment: different node modules but cant event create simple xls file (